# Populate a list with data using Meteor Angular2 rxjs and material2

Tags: mongodb, angular, meteor, rxjs, angular-material2

I am starting out with [BoilerPlate](https://github.com/0mkara/meteor-ng-material-baby/) and so far I have had some success learning and implementing my first full stack application.  The question comes where its time to retrieve data from the mongodb and display it on the UI.

I have a "both" folder that contains models and collections.

This is my "bill" model.

```
export interface Bill {
    name: string;
    due: string;
    cost: string;
}
```

My "bill" collection

```
import { MongoObservable } from 'meteor-rxjs';
import { Bill } from '../models/bills.model';

export const Bills = new MongoObservable.Collection<Bill>('Bills');
```

I have a function that runs on server startup that populates this collection with some test data. I have verified via mongo shell.

I would like to represent this data on the UI like this...

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let bill of bills | async">
    <h3 md-line>{{bill.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{bill.cost}}</p>
    <p md-line>{{bill.due}}</p>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

my angular component looks like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bills',
    animations: [routerTransition('routeAnimations')],
    template
})

export class BillsComponent implements OnInit {
    bills: Observable<Bill[]>;
    public result: any;

    constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) {
        console.log('constructed bills component');
         this.bills = Bills.find({}).zone();
    }
```

I am essentially trying to use concepts from this [Tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding) to help develop this app.

The problem is that the `md-list` is empty and the mongo database has 3 entries.  I have searched for the last couple of days and can't seam to figure it out. Most examples using this methodology show that I am doing it right. 
 No errors and debugging this shows that "this.bills" in the component is an observable.

Comment: I have tried to populate a basic unordered list and use the *ngFor in the list item with the same results.  I then populated a local array inside the component with some test data and the unordered list was able to populate the test data.  It must be something within the line `this.bills = Bills.find({}).zone();`